# Is there any equivalent to the atempo ffmpeg audio filter but for avconv to speed up video & audio?

Tags: ubuntu, audio, video, ffmpeg, avconv

As noted [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20speed%20up%20/%20slow%20down%20a%20video), we could speedup audio with `ffmpeg` using:

```
$ ffmpeg -i input.mkv -filter:a "atempo=2.0" -vn output.mkv
```

But on `Ubuntu`, `ffmpeg` is replaced by `avconv`, and the `atempo` filter is not available in `avconv`.

My question is:

1. Are there any alternatives to the `atempo` filter to use with `avconv`, or how to speed up audio AND video using `avconv`?
2. How to speed up a video file (if you have better ideas)?

Comment: @illuminÉ By video, I mean video with sound, usually when you speedup a video, I'd expect the sound also keeps up with the video.

Comment: @illuminÉ Thanks.  I will look into sox.  Currently I add ppa for ffmpeg.  I'm a newbie to video/audio editing :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to circumvent the fact that the *atempo* filter is not available for `avconv`(yet the *setpts* video filter is). Simply use another tool like [`sox`](http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html) to do the [audio part](https://superuser.com/questions/519649/tool-to-bulk-speed-up-convert-an-audio-file)(adjust mapping depending on streams):

```
avconv -i input.mkv -c copy -map 0:0 video.raw                   #copy raw video stream
avconv -i input.mkv -c copy -map 0:1 audio.raw                   #copy raw audio stream
sox audio.raw audioq.raw speed 4                         #speed up(4x)audio&pitch
sox audio.raw audioq.raw tempo 4                         #or, to preserve pitch
avconv -i video.raw -filter:v "setpts=0.25*PTS" output.raw #speed up (4x) video
avconv -i output.raw -i audioq.raw final.mkv             #combine outputs to .mkv
```

There is surely a simpler way to do this but I've tried with some random .mkv file and it worked.

Comment: if you use 'sox tempo', the '-m' or '-s' flags should give a better quality. as noted [here](http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html), these calculate an appropriate "segment" for music or speech.

Answer (score 4):

Rater than use `avconv` why not just switch to `ffmpeg` instead. The project offers a statically built version which you can simply download and install + use in place.

- [FFMpeg download page](https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html)
- [Static builds](https://www.johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/)

Once downloaded and unpacked you can run it like so:

```
./ffmpeg ....
```

Comment: @illuminÉ Actually you could work around this limitation by using `-filter_complex` to chain the speedup.  I think `ffmepg` online manual mentioned that :)

Comment: I actually added the PPA for ffmpeg.  Thanks though :D

Comment: @gongzhitaao Thanks for the heads up, I actually had not paid attention!:) Indeed, as I was saying it certainly is easier with ffmpeg! You're welcome!